# How to fix program that extracts comments from C++ code to another text file?(Problem:single line comments inside of block comments)

Tags: c++, file, text, comments

I've created a program that takes C++ code in one text file and outputs all of the comments from that code in another text file, however I've encountered a special situation, where the program does not do the necessary task. While it does extract most of the comments, it does not extract single line comments which are inside of a block comment. 
Here is the C++ source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream fin; //file that will be read
    fstream fout; //file that will be written
    string row; // string variable which will store each row of the code
    string comment; // string which will store the comment
    string blockCommentStart = "/*";
    string lineCommentStart = "//"; // the beginning symbols of comments so that they could be identified in the text file
    string result;

    fin.open("code.txt", ios::in);
    fout.open("endresult.txt", ios::out);

    if(!fin) cout << "File not found" << endl;
    if(!fout) cout << "File not found" << endl;

    getline(fin, row); //reads the first row from the file
    while(fin) 
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<row.size();i++) 
            {
                while (row[i]!= '/') //goes through the row until it finds the '/' symbol
                {
                    if(i>row.size()) break;

                    i++;
                }
                if (i>row.size()) break; //checks if the end of the row has been reached



                if(row[i+1] =='/' || row[i+1]=='*') //checks if the next symbol is the start of a comment
                {
                    result = row[i];
                    result+= row[i+1];

                }

                if(result!="")
                {
                    comment = ""; //creates a single line comment
                    if(result==lineCommentStart)
                    {
                        while (i<row.size())
                        {
                            comment+=row[i]; //the comment string adds the symbols of the comment
                            i++;
                        }
                        fout << comment << endl; //comment gets output in the endresult.txt file
                        comment=""; //after the output, it is renewed to the beginning stage
                        break;
                    }

                    comment = ""; //creates a block comment
                    if(result==blockCommentStart || result==lineCommentStart)
                    {
                        comment=row[i];
                        comment+=row[i+1]; //writes the comment symbols in the output file
                        i+=2; //jumps over the comment symbols

                    while(row[i]!='/') //adds symbols to the comment whilst it hasn't reached the end symbols
                        {
                            if(i>=row.size())
                            {
                                fout << comment << " "; //comment gets output in the endresult.txt file
                                getline(fin, row); //reads the next line
                                comment = ""; //comment string gets renewed for the new row
                                i=0; //moves the iterator back to the beginning position
                            }

                            comment+=row[i];
                            i++;
                        }
                        fout << comment << endl;


                    }
                    result = ""; //results gets renewed to the beginning stage
                }
            }
            getline(fin,row); // reads the next line
    };
    fin.close();
    fout.close(); //after the work is done, the files are closed
}
```

Here is the content of the test file code.txt:

```
// merge algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::merge, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector
using namespace std;
int main () {
  vector<int> first = {1,5,8};
  int second[] = {2,3,7,9};
  vector<int> v(7);
  merge (first.begin(),first.end(),second,second+4,v.begin());
  std::cout << "The resulting vector contains:";
  for(auto &i: v) cout<<i<<" "; cout<<endl;
}
/*
Comment which is in
multiple

// single line inside block

lines or a block
*/


//comment
```

Here is the result of the program(endresult.txt):

```
// merge algorithm example
// std::cout
// std::merge, std::sort
// std::vector
/* Comment which is in multiple   /
//comment
```

So as one can see, the single line comment inside the block comment breaks the entire block comment structure. I would really appreciate any help or insight on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

EDIT: I've tried solving this further by replacing the

```
while(row[i]!='/')
```

line in the code near the blockComment segment with

```
while(row[i]!='/' || row[i-1]!='*')
```

and it now seems to include the single line comment however the formatting is a little wonky because the entire block comment then gets output together in a single line. Is there an easy solution to this, something like adding an endline after every row that is read?

Comment: Since block comments only ends on \*/, you should be using a flag instead, so on encountering /\*, set the flag, and just store anything you encounter as comment until you get the \*/

Comment: @Martheen Thank you for your input, however I am not too familiar with the use of flags so I tried a different approach(documented in the edit portion of the submission). It seems like now the only problem left is for me to figure out a way to format the block comments so that they're not output as a single line.

Comment: Flag is just a boolean variable. As for endline, just add '\n' or '\n\r' depending on your OS